# Wrap dynamic array with shared_ptr by make_shared

Tags: c++, arrays, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I want to write some bytes to an array. To make use of modern C++ I have decided to use a smart pointer.

```
#include <memory>
#include <cstdint>

using namespace std;

void writeUint32_t(uint32_t value, unsigned char* p){
    *p     = static_cast<unsigned char>((value >> 24) & 0xFF);
    *(++p) = static_cast<unsigned char>((value >> 16) & 0xFF);
    *(++p) = static_cast<unsigned char>((value >>  8) & 0xFF);
    *(++p) = static_cast<unsigned char>((value      ) & 0xFF);
}

int main(){
    auto buf = make_shared<unsigned char[]>(512);
    uint32_t data = 1234;
    writeUint32_t(data, buf.get() + 8);
}
```

However, I am receiving the following compilation error:

```
u.cpp:15:37: error: invalid use of array with unspecified bounds
 writeUint32_t(data, buf.get() + 8);
                                 ^
u.cpp:15:38: error: cannot convert ‘unsigned char (*)[]’ to ‘unsigned char*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘void writeUint32_t(uint32_t, unsigned char*)’
 writeUint32_t(data, buf.get() + 8);
```

I am using `g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) 5.4.0 20160609`
Is there a way to use smart pointers in such a situation?

Comment: Works with clang. [Livedemo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Q9406vfvUZQOr8JW). So what compiler are you using. And I think you cannot use make_shared this way.

Comment: `g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2) 5.4.0 20160609`. For me does not work even with `clang version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4`.

Comment: The problem is the make_shared. I am not 100% sure, but I think you cannot use make_shared to create a pointer to an array. Create a shared_ptr with an array deleter and you are fine. See my Livedemo.

Comment: In C++14, `shared_ptr` does not support array types (nor does `make_shared`). Support for array types is being added to C++17, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend you use `std::vector<unsigned char> vec(512);`, wrapping contiguous dynamic arrays is exactly what it's for. Getting the raw buffer pointer is as simple as `vec.data()`;

If the vector needs to be shared, than you can still use a smart pointer

```
auto p_vec = make_shared<vector<unsigned char>>(512);
```

You'll get the benefit of reference counting with virtually no overhead due to using vector, **and** you'll get the entire vector API.

Comment: Probably the better solution proposed. But IMHO, `shared_ptr` on vector isn't necessary in many case, according moving semantic. Aslo, to complete, I will rewrite `writeUint32_t` to use iterator in complement of vector

Comment: @Garf365, you are probably correct on both accounts. But I operated under the assumption that the OP has a set API (that accepts raw pointers), and only their own data is up for modification.

Comment: Except when you don't want the **entire vector API**, e.g. you explicitly don't want someone to push or pop from the buffer; and you don't really need anything except of size being attached to it.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that `shared_ptr` points to the pointer (`std::vector`) and in order to access data you need to dereference one more time. Every time when you dereference you access memory in the another CPU cache line (or even worse on the another page). In case if you create `shared_ptr` for "C-array", the `shared_ptr` points to data itself.

Answer (score 15):

Don't use [`std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) with raw array, it won't construct an array as you expected, but will try to create a pointer to the type you specified, i.e. `unsigned char[]`. That's why you get a `unsigned char (*)[]` when use `get()`, as the error message said.

And [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) will delete the pointer by `delete` by default, not `delete[]`, which should be used for array. You need to specify a customized deleter for it, but `std::make_shared` does not allow you to specify it.

You could (1) Initialize `std::shared_ptr` directly and specify the deleter, like

```
std::shared_ptr<unsigned char> buf(new unsigned char[512], [](unsigned char* p)
{
    delete[] p;
});
```

(2) Use [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) instead, which provides a specified version for array, including call `delete[]` when deallocating and providing `operator[]` (`std::shared_ptr` will support it from C++17).

```
auto buf = std::make_unique<unsigned char[]>(512);
```

(3) Consider about `std::vector<unsigned char>` and `std::array<unsigned char>`.

Comment: `std::vector<unsigned char>` adds another level of indirection and `std::array<unsigned char>` requires that the size be known at compile time. Neither is equivalent to the desired `std::shared_ptr<char[]>`.

Comment: Is there ever a situation in industry practice where you would prefer to have a shared_ptr to a dynamic array vs just using a vector>

Answer (score 7):

If you really want to use a `shared_ptr` with an array for this (rather than a vector as suggested by StoryTeller), your type should be `unsigned char` rather than `unsigned char[]`. To make sure the array is correctly deleted, you need to specify an array deleter to pass to the `shared_ptr` constructor (so you can't use `make_shared` as this doesn't allow you to specify the deleter):

```
auto buf = std::shared_ptr<unsigned char>(new unsigned char[512], std::default_delete<unsigned char[]>());
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use:

```
std::make_shared<unsigned char[]>(512);
```

That because there is no *template specialization* for `Type[]`.
That because actually [`std::shared_ptr<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) **does not** support `operator[]` yet. It will in the new standard *C++17*:

> operator[] (C++17)

---

A solution it could be using a *STL container*, or IMO better: [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

Indeed, `std::unique_ptr` supports `operator[]`.

*Since C++14*, you can:

```
auto buffer = std::make_unique<unsigned char[]>(512);
buffer[index];
```

It's exception-safe, almost 0 overhead, and it can be use as a array buffer.

Moreover the deallocation of the buffer is correctly handled by the correct call of `delete[]` operator.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you really need `shared_ptr<T[]>` and not `unique_ptr<T[]>`, I would suggest to use `boost::shared_ptr`. It supports `T[]`.

Pros:

1. C++20 still does not support `shared_ptr<T[]>`. Tried g++ 11.3 and VS2022.
2. Creating the array with the `std::shared_ptr<T>(new T[size], deleter)` expression is not efficient, as memory for the reference counter is allocated elsewhere.
3. `std::shared_ptr<std::vector>` is not efficient either, as shared_ptr points to the pointer. In order to access the data you need to dereference one more time.

`boost::shared_ptr` solves all the problems:

1. The memory for the data and the reference counter is allocated in one shot and is allocated nearby which improves the data locality
2. The `shared_ptr` points to data itself rather than to another pointer as in case of `std::vector`

Following is a snippet:

```cpp
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

int main()
{
   auto arr = boost::make_shared<unsigned char[]>(512);
}
```